# 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, button, gtk

Hello i am working on given code here i am getting

> 'str' object has no attribute 'read' i also tried
>
> byteImgIO = io.BytesIO(byteImgIO.read())

function but after that  i am gatting

> Local variable referenced before assignment

```
 def extract(self, button):
    #if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    #   print('Usage: python ocr_simple.py image.jpg')
    #   sys.exit(1)
    #sys.argv[1] = imgPath
    #imgPath = sys.argv[1]
    print(imgPath)
    byteImgIO = io.BytesIO()
    byteImg = Image.open(imgPath)
    byteImg.save(byteImgIO, "JPEG")
    byteImgIO.seek(0)
    byteImg = byteImgIO.read()
    dataBytesIO = io.BytesIO(byteImg)
    img = Image.open(dataBytesIO)
    #img = Image.open(imgPath)
    width, height = img.size
    new_size = width*6, height*6
    img = img.resize(new_size, Image.LANCZOS)
    img = img.convert('L')
    img = img.point(lambda x: 0 if x < 155 else 255, '1')
    imagetext = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
    print(imagetext)
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        tim=imagetext
        f.write(tim)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you explain more about the context, what libraries you're using, etc?

Comment: Uncomment this line **#imgPath = sys.argv[1]**

Answer (score 0):

## !/usr/bin/pythonfrom PIL

from gi.repository import Gtk
import os
import sys

import requests
import io
import pytesseract

from PIL import Image

## from pytesseract import image_to_string

import cv2

Hii i am using this libraries